# ¿Como realizar mi consulta con active record en yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii, activerecord

Tengo la siguiente consulta que ya verifique que sirviera:

```
select T1.* from flujoAreas T1 JOIN 
(select idSolicitud, MAX(fecha) as Max_Fecha from flujoAreas group by idSolicitud) T2
on T1.idSolicitud = T2.idSolicitud and T1.fecha = T2.Max_Fecha 
where T1.idSolicitud in (9954,9947)
```

pero ando usando el framework de php Yii2, en al cual soy nueva y necesito pasar mi consulta en Active Record, no lo he podido conseguir, y solo lo pude pasar a algo que acepta el framework pero que no es active record, de igual, no entiendo porque no funciona y me entrega un arreglo vació, coloco lo que he echo y cualquier observación que tengan de mi código es bien recibida.

```
$subQuery2 = (new \yii\db\Query)
              ->select(['idSolicitud','MAX(fecha) AS Max_Fecha'])
              ->from('flujoAreas')
              ->orderBy('idSolicitud');

        $query7 = new \yii\db\Query;

        $query7->select('flujoAreas.*')
          ->from('flujoAreas')
          ->innerJoin(['u' => $subQuery2], 'u.idSolicitud= flujoAreas.idSolicitud and u.Max_Fecha = flujoAreas.fecha')
          ->where(['in', 'flujoAreas.idarea', $array]);

        $command = $query7->createCommand();
        $objeto = $command->queryAll();
```

Al hacer un `var_dump($ojeto)` este me devuelve `array(0) { }`, con mi consulta norma si devuelve los dos registros que busque en el where();

Answer (score 1):

te recomiendo que imprimas tu sql formado con active record , para hacerlo es tan simple como esto .

```
echo $command->rawSql;
```

He probado tu código y comparado con el SQL que has proporcionado  y la unica diferencia que hay esta en el "GROUP BY", entonces para que  fuera igual seberias corregir  el "orderBy" y poner "groupBy".

```
$subQuery2 = (new \yii\db\Query)
          ->select(['idSolicitud','MAX(fecha) AS Max_Fecha'])
          ->from('flujoAreas')
          ->groupBy('idSolicitud');
          //->orderBy('idSolicitud');

    $query7 = new \yii\db\Query;

    $query7->select('flujoAreas.*')
      ->from('flujoAreas')
      ->innerJoin(['u' => $subQuery2], 'u.idSolicitud= flujoAreas.idSolicitud and u.Max_Fecha = flujoAreas.fecha')
      ->where(['in', 'flujoAreas.idarea', $array]);

    $command = $query7->createCommand();
    //Aqui puedes  impimir tu sql para ver si esta como tu quieres
    // echo $command->rawSql;
    $objeto = $command->queryAll();
```